# HighCharts: Custom button next to legend inside chart area

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to create a custom button next to legend as per below use-case:
1) button right of horizontal legend
2) button below vertical legend

[JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/qd9js9oj/9/)

Using chart renderer, I can add the button on chart but its coordinates are fixed. It is rendered as rectangle on chart (got to know after inspecting button using developer tools). Is there any way I can always keep this custom button next to any element inside chart, in my case, next to legend.

```
chart.renderer.button(...); // code inside jsfiddle link
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [lagend labelFormatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.labelFormatter) with `useHTML:true` to add button next to It.If You are using vertical legend you can add line break in legend `labelFormatter`

```js
var chart;
chart=new Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
       legend: {

        useHTML:true,
        labelFormatter: function () {
            return this.name + ' (click to hide) <button onclick="buttonAction()">Button Action</button>';
        }
    },


    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});

function buttonAction(){
if(chart.series[0].visible==true){ //button click will interfere with legend text click
 chart.series[0].visible=false
}else{
 chart.series[0].visible=true
}
console.log('button clicked')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: I am also showing Checkbox with each legend item and with your solution, button is appearing between legend item text and checkbox: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/bkeu3mLp/)

Comment: According to your post above only button was required. Anyways check https://jsfiddle.net/bkeu3mLp/1/. when using `useHTML:true` you can add html elements.